# How to get information from an image of a document, like name, CPF, RG, on python?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm sorry for the title of my question if it doesn't let clear my problem.

I'm trying to get information from an image of a document using tesseract, but it doesn't work well on pictures (on print screens of text it works very well). I want to ask if somebody know a technique that can help me. I think that letting the image black and white, where the information I want is in black would help a lot, but I don't know how to do that.

I will be glad if somebody knows how to help me. (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using opencv might help to preprocess the image before passing it to tesseract.

I usually follow these steps

1. Convert the image to grayscale
2. If the texts in the image are small, resize the image using cv2.resize()
3. Blur the image (GaussianBlur or MedianBlur)
4. Apply threshhold to make the text prominent (cv2.threshold)
5. Use tesseract config to instruct tesseract to look for specific characters.
   For example If the image contains only alphanumeric upper case english text then passing
   config='-c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" would help.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

I want to try the thing you said. Do you know any tutorial to learn how to use opencv?

Comment: I had found this youtube video to be a good tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oXlwWbU8l2o&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org. The other reference point would be opencv documentation for image processing. https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/da8/tutorial_table_of_content_imgproc.html